# How to split jquery source code into multiple files when using the module pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, module-pattern

I've got some problems splitting up my jquery source code into more than one file. My real source code is a bit more complicated but the following simple example shows my problem very good. At first I would like to show you a working example with only one javascript file. Afterwards, I will describe what I tried in order to split the javascript into two files.

My html code looks like this ("./jquery" is a symbolic link to my local jquery download):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="./jquery"></script>
    <script src="./file1.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The jquery source code in file1.js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var Test = (function() {
    var content = $('#content');

    var init = function() {
      content.html('<p>test</p>');
    };

    return {
      init: init
    }
  })();

  Test.init();
});
```

After opening the page, "test" is displayed so that this example works as expected.

But now I want to put the whole Test part into another file file2.js. My html is basically the same but gets an additional line:

```
<script src="./file2.js"></script>
```

file1.js now contains only the call of the init function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Test.init();
});
```

and file2.js contains the definition of Test:

```
var Test = (function() {
  var content = $('#content');

  var init = function() {
    content.html('<p>test</p>');
  };

  return {
    init: init
  }
})();
```

When I open the page, "test" is not displayed any more. In order to make sure that the init function is called at all, I added a console.log("test"); to the init function which is working fine. Therefore, I suppose that the function might be called before the DOM is ready, but actually I am pretty clueless. Maybe someone can give me a hint how to make that run.

Best regards and thanks in advance!

Comment: See jQuery code on [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do several things according to your preferences...
1. Move your scripts to the end of the HTML file intead than in header...

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
  <script src="./jquery"></script>
  <script src="./file2.js"></script>
  <script src="./file1.js"></script>
</html>
```

Think this problem secuencially... if you don't want to declare a var in each module referring an element in your DOM you need that the element exists first, then you can declare the "global" var to the module **content**. This way your original file2.js works.

Another way is to declare the content "global" to your module but init this in your init function...

```
var Test = (function() {
  var content;

  var init = function() {
    content = $('#content');
    content.html('<p>test</p>');
  };

  return {
    init: init
  }
})();
```

Now you can use the content variable in all of your module's functions.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: Just moving the script definitions to the end of the html file helped me for both the theoretical example provided here and my original source code as well.:)

Answer (score 0):

file1 depends on file2. Make sure file1 comes ordinally after file2 in your html.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your file2.js as follows:

```
var Test = {
  content : $('#content'),
  init : function() {        
    Test.content.html('<p>test</p>');
  }
  //, include other functions here
};
```

Modify your file1.js as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   Test.init();
})
```

Now declare `file2.js` before your declare `file1.js` because `file1.js` is referencing a function from `file2.js` .

Comment: Firebug says "TypeError: Test.init is not a function".  Do I have to call it in another way?

Comment: I have modified my answer . Try using this as solution.

Comment: This is working but it is not what I am actually searching for. In my original source code, I have a few more methods than only an init method and I want to keep this structure as it is suggested here: https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/concepts/

Comment: I have again modified the solution. Please try and let me know

Comment: It doesn't work:

- SyntaxError: missing } after property list in file2.js, line 5
- ReferenceError: Test is not defined in file1.js, line 17

Comment: Sorry, there was an extra `;` which i have removed now from file2.js. Please try again.

Comment: This works again, but it seems to be impossible to have variables outside functions. When I have two or more functions changing the same div, I would have to add a line like "var content = $('#content');" to each function which is rather bad. :(

Comment: you can move the common variable outside the function, as i have done now. Please check and let me know.

Comment: But in that case, the variable is not private any more. Furthermore, I am not sure if it is possible to have private methods in your solution. Basically, my idea was to stick to the module pattern from the jquery learning page and find a way to define and use the object in different files.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have made the variable private. You can add other functions similar to `init` separated by `commas`. Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. As described above, just moving the script definitions to the end of the html file did the trick and seems to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

[AngularJS](http://www.angularbasics.co.uk/#) offers dependency injection, modules, services, factories and all sorts of other goodness.  Takes a bit to get used to, but well worth it IMO: much cleaner abstraction of javascript from DOM, data from presentation etc.

I appreciate your question is JQuery specific, but especially if you're starting a new site, I suggest you give Angular a try.